# How can I get an viewport fit vertical line?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a page that can have lines to separate this sort of stuff! See the picture below!
[image: The design that I want it to be like!]

Now the I tried many ways using empty div but still causes problems as it takes the whole page downwards. And I also thought of another way using **hr tag** and then use transform property to rotate it but still won't work!

Here is the link to the entire thing, few things aren't made, 
[the project that I am trying to make!](https://codepen.io/srvrawat/pen/ExaoJaM)

And here is the portion of code that I used before

```
<hr id="sidebar">

    #sidebar {
        transform =  rotate(90deg);
    }
```

Thanks any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this design using `:before`.

Please review my code and get back to me if you have any question.

Hope it will help you. :)

Please try this css.

```
    .slider:before {
        content: '';
        width: 1px;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 80px;
    }
    .slider {
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: @jaydeep_patel this worked perfectly to fix itself with the boxes below! However, the trouble now is the top area! Like I want to cover up the logo area too! Check the code I wanna make it a box sort! And yeah this generates a scrollbar in chrome too! I wanna eliminate that!

Comment: @SouravSinghRawat you just need to set " top:0 " into .slider:before. And remove " 
position: relative; " from .slider. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this vertical line.

```
hr:before{
  content: "";
  width:2px;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:7%;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Swati, thanks for your reply and it did work but there is something that I would like to know more! If you see the code and image above, is there any way I can get this line to permanently stick to boxes below! The Up and Down ones!